# Mathplotlib, реально ли сделать круговой срез на данном графике 3д и редактировать его значения?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Необходимо сделать срез круга внутри 3д графика, с помощью которого можно было бы редактировать значения и менять чувствительность графика в заданной точке. На рисунке выделил примерную область круга, в которой можно было бы отдельно от всего графика менять значения. Т.е. на плоскости этого квадрата нарисовать овал, а на территории овала управлять уровнем нормального распределения. Реально ли такое?

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def makeData():
    x = np.linspace(3, 2.5, 100)
    y = np.linspace(3, 2.5, 100)

    xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
##    print("Двумерную матрица", xgrid, ygrid)

    z = np.random.normal(xgrid, ygrid)  
##    print("Значения функции", z)
    
    return xgrid, ygrid, z

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x, y, z = makeData()

##    x1 = -3
##    y2 = -6
##    z3 = -9
##    mask = np.sqrt((x-x1)**2+(y-y2)**2+(z-z3)**2)
##    print(mask)
##    r = 3
##    for x in range(0,100):
##            for y in range(0,100):
##                if mask[x,y] < r:
##                        mask[x,y] = 0
##                elif mask[x,y] >= r:
##                        mask[x,y] = 2.5
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    axes = plt.axes(projection="3d")

    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('red_blue', ['b', 'y', 'r'], 256)
    axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, color='#11aa55', cmap=cmap)

##    axes.plot_surface(x1,y2,mask, color='#11aa55', cmap=cmap)
    plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Честно говоря, непонятно, что вы хотите. Нужны ещё разъяснения, иллюстрации.

Comment: изменил, теперь думаю понятно будет

Comment: Да, про срез стало понятнее, а вот чем вы хотите управлять - всё ещё не совсем. Да, и у вас что вообще - `Jupyter Notebook` или что-то ещё? В юпитере есть прям слайдеры которыми можно менять значения, в других инструментах будет другое.

Comment: Хочу внутри этого среза менять значения (шум) не влияя на остальной график. Насчет слайдера пока не думал, потому что сомневаюсь что получится реализовать срез. Есть много примеров в 2д исполнении, но 3д не видел.

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, причем здесь matplotlib. данные вы берете из numpy array. вот и делайте в нем круговую маску и меняйте там значения так, как вам нужно. а потом уже выводите с помощью matplotlib.

Comment: а как получить круговую маску? У меня получаются две разные матрицы (разделенные друг от друга). Отредактировал код.

Comment: Подсказка выше - правильная. Matplotlib  - это библиотека визуализации, а не численного решения математических задач.  Именно это и есть "поиск среза" -  это задача сечения плоскостью вашей фигуры. Поэтому меняем архитектуру системы. Указание "сдвинуть срез выше ниже, наклонить относительно плоскости ХY  и пр." решаем соответствующим инструментом. Например - внутри numpy. А полученный результат -  отрисовываем на графике.  С нужной "чувствительностью" или что еще там менять надо.  Ну, я бы шел вот таким путем.